# External evaluations — selecting one of several Python versions

Tags: python, external-calls

I have several Python versions installed and registered to Mathematica:

```
FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]
```

[image]

**When I run the following code which one of Pythons was used?**

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "2+2"]
(*4*)
```

**How to specify I want to use version 2.7.8 or version 3.9.0?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two versions seem to work:

```
ExternalEvaluate[{"Python", "Version" -> "3.9.0"}, "2+2"]
ExternalEvaluate[{"Python", "Executable" -> "C:\\Python39\\python.exe"}, "2+2"]
```